# Saving multiple pandas DataFrames to SQLite in a single transaction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am on working on an application that works with several dozen pandas DataFrames in memory and I am using SQLite as an application file format. Currently, I am essentially saving each DataFrame like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=data3)

my_dfs = {
    "Table1": df1,
    "Table2": df2,
    "Table3": df3,
}
with sqlite3.connect("my_db.sqlite") as my_db:
    for table_name, df in my_dfs.items():
        df.to_sql(table_name, my_db, if_exists="replace")
```

However, for the several dozen DataFrames I have, this iterating-over-my-collection-of-tables-and-using-`.to_sql()` is getting *REALLY* slow.

I have just spent a half-hour doing various internet/SO searches for things like "bulk save pandas dataframe tables to sqlite" and "save list of dataframes to sqlite tables" but I am not seeing anything. Is there someway of doing this efficiently in a single transaction to my database?

Currently, it takes around 5-6 mins to save all my tables to the database! Yikes!

Thanks for any input people can offer.

Comment: why don't you concatenate the table, and move a single one?

Comment: I do that in some instances. For the tables which I cannot do this, say Table 2 and Table 3 in this example (assume Table 1 represents many tables already concatenated), I still follow this one-at-a-time process. However, I have dozens of these tables which represent information from completely different domains and this one-at-a-time method of using .to_sql() is incredibly slow.

Comment: what's the alternative? I'd assume you have an alternative, and that alternative is faster than your current implementation. You can then find out what the alternative does that is better than your current implementation. Is there a for loop? is the connection to the sql database the issue? do you have to dump down into sqlalchemy land to do the migration?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I don’t have an alternative: as far as I know the “for loop” method I have laid out above in the example is the only way I know how to do it. I am currently using this process for development but waiting 6+ minutes for tables to save, doing one write transaction at a time, is probably the most inefficient way to do it. There is no problem connecting to the database, so-to-speak, because I am using SQLite (local file). What I am hoping to achieve is multiple tables in a single write transaction. Can sqlalchemy do this? Never used it, know of it by name only.

Comment: if that's the case, I'd suggest converting data into a text file/csv, then write a custom function to load the csv into the sqlite db - it should be faster. There is a great [blog post](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql) for postgres; see if you can tweak it to fit your goal for sqlite

Comment: Yes, it seems that pandas cannot conveniently do anything other than .to_sql(), which seems to be slow for many. It appears the way to go is to manually convert to text and stream it in with sqlalchemy, or something to that effect.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it's all I ever wanted. Thanks!